# VUGEN 11.0 scripts gets corrupted always[Issues with Loadrunner]

Tags: performance, performance-testing, loadrunner

our vugen scripts getting corrupted ,there is shuffling of code in the actions which leads us to recreate the scripts,this happens when we try to save or compile the scripts.

Please anyone help us on this issue

Answer (score 2):

In all versions of LR that I have tried there is a hidden problem, and the effects are along the lines you describe.

**If you empty your TEMP folder** (with a tool or manually) **LR VuGen will loose information about all open scripts**. If you attempt to save, close or anything but kill the process you loose your script, as it tries to update the real script with garbage data.

I found this when computer did a "cleanup" every night and I accidentally left VuGen open with a script overnight ...

As far as I know this bug exists in all versions of LR, starting with at least 8.0 (I haven't tried LR 7.x or older)

Comment: What about version 12.02?

Answer (score 1):

K.Sandell.   This is not a bug, this is how Microsoft Windows applications operate.   When you open a document for modification a temporary copy is what is operated on in the folder defined by the $Temp$ environment variable.   The behavior you describe in deleting open files would also impact every other windows application from Microsoft (office applications) and many other vendors.

Answer (score 0):

You information is too general. Upload you script then others may help you. Or use LR 11.50 to have a try.

Comment: LR v11.5 is affected with the same TEMP files problem